# vb.net 3 tier architecture error message open connection

Tags: sql, vb.net

i work in vb.net project using 3 tier architecture

i have class BL include function name : show all customer and this is the code :`

```
Public Function ShowCustomer() As Customer()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim emps(-1) As Customer
    Dim e1 As Customer
    sql = "select Customer_name from Customer"
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = OBJECT_M.Exe_SQL(sql)

    While dr.Read
        e1 = New Customer
        e1.Customer_Name = dr(0)

        ReDim Preserve emps(UBound(emps) + 1)
        emps(UBound(emps)) = e1
    End While
    Return emps
End Function
```

now in interface i need to handle all Customer name and write the name in the listview

my code:

```
Dim obj As New BL
Dim obj2 As New Customer
Dim x As Integer = 1

While x <> obj.ShowCustomer.Length
    lb.Items.Add(obj.ShowCustomer(x).Customer_Name.ToString())
End While
```

but i have error message talk about this :

> Additional information: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

please can Anybody save my day ?

Comment: Please can you post the contents of Exe_SQL

Comment: My guess is OBJECT_M.Exe_SQL calls open connection but never close. Therefore the second time you are calling open connection on an already openned connection

Answer (score 1):

For SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, DataTable, DataSet (and any other disposable object) make sure to Dispose() of the object when you are done.

If you don't call Dispose() (or Close() in this case) connections will remain open and you will get memory and handle leaks.

The easist way is to use the `Using` keyword (which will also dispose in the case of an exception or other short circuiting event:

```
Using dr As SqlDataReader = OBJECT_M.Exe_SQL(sql)

    While dr.Read
        e1 = New Customer
        e1.Customer_Name = dr(0)

        ReDim Preserve emps(UBound(emps) + 1)
        emps(UBound(emps)) = e1   
    End While

End Using
```

Make sure to do the same in the object I have detailed above in OBJECT_M.Exe_SQL, once you have called Dispose()/Close() on an oject you will not be able to use the instance of the object again and will have to create a new instance.

Refer to the documentation for more examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Also while there is nothing wrong with using arrays, you may find it easire to use a List(of T) which you can later convert to an using ToArray().